# SetForegroundAsync to create foreground service in ListenableWorker of Workmanager not working

Tags: android, android-workmanager, foregroundnotification

I am using ListenableWorker to run a backgroundtask in workmanager, I want to show Foreground Notification to the user about the work is being done. But SetForegroundAsync function under OnStart function of the worker is not generating notification. Here is the code -

```
class PostUploadWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): ListenableWorker(context, params) {

   companion object{
       fun getBuilder(postDtoJson: String,
                      postEntityId: String? = null,
                      type: String? = null,
                      mediaId: String? = null
       ): OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder {
           val data = workDataOf(
                   POST to postDtoJson,
                   POST_ENTITY_ID to postEntityId,
                   MEDIA_TYPE to type,
                   MEDIA_ID to mediaId
           )
           return OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PostUploadWorker::class.java).setInputData(data)
       }
   }

   private fun getPostMediaType(mediaTye: String?): String {
       if (mediaTye == TYPE_VIDEO) {
           return PostMediaType.VIDEO.stringName
       }
       return PostMediaType.AUDIO.stringName
   }

   private fun createForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
       // Use a different id for each Notification.
       val notificationId = 1
        val notificationn = createNotification()
       Timber.e("asdf: /api/v1/feed inside CreateForegroundInfo ${notificationn}")
       return ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notificationn)
   }

   private fun createNotification(): Notification {
       // This PendingIntent can be used to cancel the Worker.
      val intent = WorkManager.getInstance(AppController.getInstance()).createCancelPendingIntent(id)

       val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder( applicationContext, "123")
               .setContentTitle("uploading post")
               .setTicker("title")
               .setOngoing(true)
               .setChannelId("123")
               .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
               .addAction(R.drawable.notification_bg,"cancel",intent)
    /*   if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
           createNotificationChannel(channelId, name).also {
               builder.setChannelId(it.id)
           }
       }  */
       return builder.build()
   }

   override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> {
       Timber.e("post upload worker")
       setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo())

       val future: SettableFuture<Result> = SettableFuture.create()
       val mediaId = inputData.getString(MEDIA_ID)
       val type = inputData.getString(MEDIA_TYPE)
       val post = inputData.getString(POST)
       val postEntityId = inputData.getString(POST_ENTITY_ID)!!

       return try {
           val postDto = Gson().fromJson(post, SubmitPostDto::class.java)
           val uploadPostDto = postDto.toUploadPost()
           if (type == TYPE_VIDEO) {
               uploadPostDto.videoId = mediaId
           } else {
               uploadPostDto.audioId = mediaId
           }

           var extraInfo = ExtraInfoDto()
           PostCreationRepository.getSinglePost(postEntityId)
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .doOnSuccess {
                   extraInfo = Gson().fromJson(it?.extraInfo, ExtraInfoDto::class.java)
               }.subscribe()

           PostCreationRepository.uploadPost(uploadPostDto, object : ObservableCallBack {

               override fun observableSuccess(`object`: Any?, observableType: String?, observableId: String?) {
                   Timber.e("asdf: /api/v1/feed upload worker success $uploadPostDto")
                   val idModel = `object` as IdModel
                   Timber.e("asdf: /api/v1/feed upload worker success2 ${idModel.id}")
                   PostCreationRepository.setPostUploaded(postDto.postId, idModel.id)
                   val data = workDataOf(
                       POST_SERVER_ID to idModel.id,
                       POST_ENTITY_ID to postEntityId
                   )
                   future.set(Result.success(data))
                   logEvent(extraInfo, Value.Success, getPostMediaType(type), idModel.id)
               }

               override fun observableFailure(`object`: Any?, observableType: String?, observableId: String?) {
                   Timber.e("asdf: /api/v1/feed upload worker failure $`object`")
                   PostCreationRepository.setPostFailStatus(postDto.postId)
                   future.set(Result.failure())
                   logEvent(extraInfo, Value.Failed, getPostMediaType(type))
               }
           })
           future
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           Timber.e("upload worker $e")
           PostCreationRepository.setPostFailStatus(postEntityId)
           future.set(Result.failure())
           future
       }
   }

   private fun logEvent(extraInfo: ExtraInfoDto, status: String, type: String, postId: String? = null) {
       Bundle().apply {
           putString(Attr.PostId, postId)
           putString(Attr.Status, status)
           putString(Attr.Source, extraInfo.postSource)
           putString(Attr.Type, extraInfo.postType)
           putString(Attr.MediaType, type)
       }.also {
           EventTracker.trackEvent(Event.PostPublishAPIStatus, it)
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the ManiFest file required code--

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

 <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location|dataSync"
            tools:node="merge"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were follwoing the below article or something similar: [use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-workmanager-for-immediate-background-execution-a57db502603d)

You have commented out the code that sets up the notification. Uncomment the following in `createNotification()`

```kotlin
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
  createNotificationChannel(channelId, name).also {
    builder.setChannelId(it.id)
  }
}
```

The createNotificationChannel function would be as follows

```kotlin
// Create the required notification channel for O+ devices.
@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createNotificationChannel(
    channelId: String,
    name: String
): NotificationChannel {
    return NotificationChannel(
        channelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    ).also { channel ->
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```